Как сделать так что бы с твоего аккаунта в дискорде каждые 15 минут отправлялось сообщение
Как сделать так что бы с твоего аккаунта в дискорде каждые 15 минут отправлялось сообщение в какой то канал. (по id и токену дискорд) Мне нужно именно код python.

К сожалению, отправка стабильных сообщений каждые 15 минут не возможна для аккаунта (сам гуглил), только для ботов.
Бота можно создать самому. Вот статейка: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/discord.html
Код для отправки следующий (для бота):
import discord

import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(ваш_id_канала)  # Замените "ваш_id_канала" на фактический ID вашего канала
    while True:
        await channel.send('Ваше сообщение')  # Замените 'Ваше сообщение' на текст вашего сообщения
        await asyncio.sleep(900)  # 900 секунд = 15 минут

client.run('ваш_токен_бота')  # Замените "ваш_токен_бота" на фактический токен вашего бота

